# TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime has wrong IsFixedDateRule value

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the rules for if/when DST (daylight saving time) occurs for a time zone in my mobile app in Xamarin Forms. From a TimeZoneInfo I can get all the AdjustmentRules which have a DayLightTransitionStart and DayLightTransitionEnd. Each of these properties have information when DST starts and when it ends. The IsFixeDateRule is a bool saying if it happens on a specific date or a floating date (for example last Monday in March). When I try this the IsFixedDateRule property is true for all AdjustmentRules in all TimeZones and I know that this is not the case.

In Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule?view=netstandard-2.0) they have an example where they show that most values are not IsFixedDateRule. Does this has something to do with which system it is being run on? Like I mentioned am using this in my mobile app and I have tried on both an android and iOS device. I get the correct dates when DST is happening, it's just that the IsFixedDateRule is wrong.

Edit:
I am using .NET Standard 2.0.

An example of how it looks when I run the code shown on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule?view=netframework-4.8)

```
CET Adjustment rules
   Start Date: Tuesday, 01 January 2019
   End Date: Tuesday, 31 December 2019
   Time Change: 1:00 hours
   Annual Start: On March 31 at 02:00
   Annual End: On October 27 at 03:00
```

compared to their output

```
Central European Standard Time Adjustment rules  
   Start Date: Monday, January 01, 0001  
   End Date: Friday, December 31, 9999  
   Time Change: 1:00 hours  
   Annual Start: The Last Sunday of March at 2:00 AM  
   Annual End: The Last Sunday of October at 3:00 AM
```

Comment: which version of the Framework are you using?  And can you provide a specific example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: When the start and end year are in the same year then there's not a lot of floating going on.  You're ahead with what you got, Android and iOS use a very different oracle to provide timezone info.  Relying on a library to access the tz database is the alternative, except that there's never anything standard about them.

Comment: Yeah all the AdjustmentRules I get for a ZoneTimeInfo have their start date and end date in the same year. In our application we would like to get the pattern when DST starts and ends each year. Do you know any other options to achieve this?